# Regex to remove js events from subject text

Tags: php, regex

I need a regex to remove all js event 'on' (onload, obblur, etc) related code from subject string

For example: 
`autofocus оnfocus=(alert)(/OPENBUGBOUNTY/)/`/
would become:

```
autofocus
```

I tried this code:

```
$subject = preg_replace('/\son\w+=.+/', '', $subject)
```

It works only sometimes. Can anyone give me a suggest?

Comment: So you just want to remove everything after the first space? Or everything after the start of a word beginning with 'on'?

Comment: Thanks and sory everyone, there was an strange 'o' char in 'onfocus' word, it even was not detected as leter. I fixed that char and now my current regex works to do this action: "remove everything after the start of a word beginning with 'on'"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the following `regex`([DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/CwztbR/1)):

```
(?<=[\s"'])on\w+=(["']).*?\1
```

This can cover most of your cases. It works by check if there is a `space` or quotation mark `"` or `'` before the word `on` and then it takes on the entire attribute that starts with `on`, both attr name and value.